# PHPMailer manda correo con el correo de destinatario

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código para mandar un mail a una cuenta de gmail, funciona pero no del todo bien ya que yo quisiera que cuando llegue el mail apareciera el nombre de la persona que paso por método POST y el correo que el ingresa pero aparece como si yo mismo me lo mandara.

```
    <?php 

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('class.smtp.php');
require_once('PHPMailerAutoload.php');

require('vistas/mail.view.php');


    define("destino", "correo@gmail.com");
    define("farmacia", "Guillermo");

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $nombre=filter_var($_POST['nombre'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $de=filter_var($_POST['de'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $telefono=filter_var($_POST['telefono'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $asunto=filter_var($_POST['asunto'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $mensaje='
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Document</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Cuerpo del mensaje</h1>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                <td>Uno</td>
                <td>Dos</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
        </html>
        ';
        $mensaje.=filter_var($_POST['mensaje'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


        $correo = new PHPMailer(); //Creamos una instancia en lugar usar mail()

        $correo->IsSMTP();
        $correo->SMTPOptions = array('ssl' => array('verify_peer' => false,'verify_peer_name' => false,'allow_self_signed' => true));

        // optional
        // used only when SMTP requires authentication  
        $correo->SMTPAuth = true;
        $correo->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $correo->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $correo->Port = 587;
        $correo->Username = 'correo@gmail.com';
        $correo->Password = 'password';

        //Usamos el SetFrom para decirle al script quien envia el correo
        $correo->SetFrom($de, $nombre);

        //Usamos el AddReplyTo para decirle al script a quien tiene que responder el correo
        $correo->AddReplyTo($de, $nombre);

        //Usamos el AddAddress para agregar un destinatario
        $correo->AddAddress(destino, farmacia);

        //Ponemos el asunto del mensaje
        $correo->Subject = $asunto;

        /*
         * Si deseamos enviar un correo con formato HTML utilizaremos MsgHTML:
         * $correo->MsgHTML("<strong>Mi Mensaje en HTML</strong>");
         * Si deseamos enviarlo en texto plano, haremos lo siguiente:
         * $correo->IsHTML(false);
         * $correo->Body = "Mi mensaje en Texto Plano";
         */
        $correo->MsgHTML($mensaje);



        //Si deseamos agregar un archivo adjunto utilizamos AddAttachment
        //$correo->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");
        $correo->CharSet = "UTF­8";
        //$correo->Encoding = "quoted­printable";

        //Enviamos el correo
        if(!$correo->Send()) {
          echo "Hubo un error: " . $correo->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
          echo "Mensaje enviado con exito.";
        }

        }
 ?>
```

En la siguiente imagén se muestra como me llega el correo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 1):

Asi se coloca el remitente:

```
$correo->From = $from;//correo remitente
$correo->FromName = $from_name;//nombre remitente
```

y así los destinatarios:

```
$destinatarios=explode(",", $destinatarios);//$destinatarios="correo1@mail.com,correo2@mail.com"
if(!empty($destinatarios)){
foreach($destinatarios as $un_destinatario){
$correo->AddAddress($un_destinatario); //destinatarios
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando `PhpMailer`, tienes que configurar de esta forma cuando envias el email y nombre del remitente:

```
//Crea instancia PHPMailer.
$correo = new PHPMailer;
...
...
$correo->From = "remitente@tudominio.com";
$correo->FromName = "Nombre remitente";
```

ve aquí un **[ejemplo](https://www.sitepoint.com/sending-emails-php-phpmailer/)** (inglés).

Answer (score 0):

Estas poniendo las constantes que tienes en el `$correo->AddAddress`.
Es decir, en la primera parte del código pones esto:

```
define("destino", "correo@gmail.com");
define("farmacia", "Guillermo");
```

Después de ello, vas a `$correo->AddAddress(destino, farmacia);`, y pones las constantes que vas a enviar por email a la persona. Quiero suponer que la constante destino tiene tu correo, por eso siempre que se envía a tu bandeja de entrada de aparece como Yo, por que te lo estas enviando a ti mismo.

Otra cosa, `$correo->CharSet = "UTF­8";` no se escribe así, es `$correo->CharSet = "UTF­-8";`

Saludos! Espero te sirva, cualquier duda comentala.

EDITO:
Añade lo siguiente de quien te envía el correo:

```
$correo->From = $de;
```

Y para saber el nombre de la persona sería:

```
$correo->FromName = $para;
```

Comment: Si lo pongo de esa manera es porque el destinatario siempre sera ese correo , osea el mio y muchas gracias por la observación de Charset. Saludos

Comment: ¿La variable $de que almacena? ¿El correo de la persona?

Comment: Exactamente, y la variable $para almacena su nombre

Comment: EDITO:
Añade lo siguiente de quien te envía el correo:

    $correo->From = $de;
Y para saber el nombre de la persona sería:

    $correo->FromName = $para; Espero te sirva. Comentame cualquier cosa! Saludos.